# Safely delete book and its child pages

Tags: 7, nodes

I have a site with two books, each having about 300-350 pages each. I want to delete one of the book and its child pages.
I was able to load the pages using some custom coding. I also came across, `node_delete()` function which has the following code snippet:

```
db_delete('node')
  ->condition('nid', $nids, 'IN')
  ->execute();
db_delete('node_revision')
  ->condition('nid', $nids, 'IN')
  ->execute();
db_delete('history')
  ->condition('nid', $nids, 'IN')
  ->execute();
db_delete('node_access')
  ->condition('nid', $nids, 'IN')
  ->execute();
```

So, it deletes data from four tables; but I suspect there are other tables, from which the data needs to be deleted as well (one of them being `book` table). Could you please point out which of the tables needs to be checked?

Comment: Why do you  want to delete the books from code instead of using User Interface in drupal ?

Comment: because as I mentioned, book has 300-350 child pages, and deleting that number of nodes from UI would be troublesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[book_delete](http://drupal.org/project/book_delete) module will address your issue !

> Book Delete adds the ability to delete entire books to the book
>   administration page (admin/content/book). It uses a batch operation to
>   allow deletion of large books.

Take a backup of database before doing any delete actions :-)

It just worked as expected !! Follow below steps.

- Install module
- Clear Drupal Cache
- Go to admin/content/book
- Select the book you want to delete and click on delete book link next to it.
- Confirm delete !

That's it :-)